# Dynamic forum in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am developing a JSF2.0 + PrimeFaces 2.2 + ObjectDB web application. It is a forum kind of thing taken a step further: new posts appear 'instantly' in every online users browser right after posting them.

The posts can contain images and videos too, so updating a `<p:dataTable>` every 1-2 seconds with `<p:poll>` does not work; videos will restart and images will flicker.

I am interested in suggestions. How would you implement this type of functionality?

I started by making a `<h:panelGroup>` that contains all the posts. Now I want to make another `<h:panelGroup>` on top of the first, where I can add new posts.

Thanks in advance, Daniel